# ASAP library for Actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, frameworks

I'm always open to using new frameworks, especially if they allow greater flexibility when the need arises to make changes and additions.

At the same time I don't want to add an additional layer of complexity unless it's use is warranted.

Has anyone used the asaplibrary  recently on a project? Was it useful? Would you use it again?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used asaplibrary (simply because I didn't know it existed), but from a quick overview of the documentation/reference, it looks quite useful. NotificationCenter is neat all by itself.

That said, I would be hesitant to use all of its functionality without weighing other libraries against it for performance (i.e.: It has some animation functionality, but you'd be silly not to be using TweenLite/TweenMax/etc. for that task).

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to look into [splinklibrary](http://code.google.com/p/splinklibrary/), [splinkresource](http://code.google.com/p/splinkresource/) and [deepsplink](http://deepsplink.googlecode.com/) as i am the author of these libraries/frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

At [disturb](http://disturbmedia.com/) most of the projects we used to do in as2 were done using ASAP. OOP friendly in a way no many other as2 framework were. We haven't used much of it in as3, as some projects use PureMVC, Cairngorm even or tiny bespoke MVC implementations.

I am not up to date with the as3 version as I said, but I hope is as good as the as2 one. 
[Gaia](http://www.gaiaflashframework.com/) caught my eye lately though, it seems to integrate nicely with the IDE as well.

This might not be that useful, as I didn't actually answer you question and pointed you to a different framework, but these are my 2 pence.